# Passing a custom metric that is already in CloudWatch to Lambda as an object

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I already have the CloudWatch data being published to my dashboard:
[image: CloudWatch Folder]

I am trying to get this custom metric cloudwatch data into a lambda function.
[image: Specific Points from Cloudwatch Custom Metric that I want passed into lambda]

Is there a straightforward way to get this data into Lambda? I've looked at setting events on the Cloudwatch Services already and I'm not seeing any path forward with those (maybe I'm missing something). It looks like this could be accomplished with Boto3, but that seems like more of a workaround since the data is already in CloudWatch and I just need to get it to lambda somehow.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use [GetMetricData](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_GetMetricData.html) to get metric data from anywhere in including a Lambda - are you aware of it? Use the AWS SDK for the language your Lambda function targets.

Comment: That is what I am after I think. I will try this now. Thank you very much.